# Is using a label without any associated form element acceptable?

Tags: html

In my current project we have permanently disabled form controls. In those cases the form element is replaced with a `span` element on the server-side.

That creates code like this:

```
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<span id="foo">Bar</span>
```

**Question 1**: Is having a `label` element without any associated form element ( `input`, `select`, `textarea`) acceptable?

**Question 2**: If yes, would we have to remove the `for` attribute in that case (because it references an element that is not a form element)?

The spec says:

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable form-associated element in the same Document as the label element.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-label-element.html

Additonal clarification: In the above quote, what exactly is *a labelable form-associated element*?

Comment: HTML specifications do not make it mandatory to associate labels with controls, but Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 do. This is described in the technical document H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls, which also explains that the implicit association (by nesting e.g. input inside label) is not as widely supported as the explicit association via for and id attributes: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214122/4826740 is what you're looking for. TLDR what you're doing will work, but probably isn't following accessibility guidelines

Comment: Why are you replacing the form control by spans instead of just using the disabled attribute on those?

Comment: What if you had a multiple choice question, so multiple checkboxes, each checkbox already has a label, but your question also has a label, but this label can't target any specific checkbox, then what is the prefered markup for that? Fieldset + legend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, you may use a label without an associated form element.  The spec notes that a label can be associated with a form element, or contain the element within itself, but does not specify that either is required.

A label is expected to be used where phrasing content is expected.  This means:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level.

Question 2: Yes, you will need to remove the "for" attribute to be technically valid.  From the spec:

> If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of
>   a labelable form-associated element in the same Document as the label
>   element.

Since you do not have a form-labelable element, the value cannot be the ID of it, and therefore must not be specified.

To address your clarification:

From the spec, a labelable form-associated element is:

> Labelable elements 
>   Denotes elements that can be associated with label elements.
>
> ```
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen meter output progress select textarea
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As the spec itself says

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable form-associated element in the same Document as the label element.

*The for attribute may be specified*, meaning it is entirely optional.

*labelable form-associated element* means any form element to which a label can be associated. For eg. a label element is not valid for `input type='submit/reset/button'`.

**Then why use *for* with label**

The benefit is a larger clickable area. When you specify a for attribute with a label, clicking on the label area performs the same action as clicking on the form element with which the label is associated.

Hope this resolves your doubts!

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned in an answer referenced by one of the comments, a `<span>` tag should be used in place of a `<label>` when not referring directly to an `<input>` element. It is semantically incorrect to do otherwise.

**Correct:**

```
<span>This is an image</span>
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/maxresdefault.jpg" />
```

**Incorrect**

```
<label for="epic-image">This is an image</label>
<img src ="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/maxresdefault.jpg" />
```