# Why does this bootstrap text overlap image when make screen smaller

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5.1 and a fluid container, for this row I have two columns, one of 3 and one of 9

It looks okay when fullscreen:

[image]

But if I just make the window a bit smaller, the text overlays the image, even though there is plenty of unused space to the right

[image]

Why does this bootstrap text overlap image when make screen smaller?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-3 m-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="figure-img border border-dark" width="400"
        height="400">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 m-2">
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Artists
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/artist.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Artists / Sting&amp;cid=0$=Album_Artists$18649" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Sting
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Genre
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/genre.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Genres / Pop rock&amp;cid=0$=Genre$17160" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Pop rock
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Type
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/albumtype.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Types / EP&amp;cid=0$=MusicBrainz Album Type$14830" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  EP
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Label
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Labels / A&amp;M Records&amp;cid=0$=Label$18525" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  A&amp;M Records
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Year
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Years / 1988&amp;cid=0$=Date$789" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  1988
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Tried second solution provided by isherwood

It nearly works, looks fine here

[image: large screen]

and here

[image: smaller screen]

but at this point i would like image to shrink because not enough space but it doesnt

[image]

I tried adding back in `img-fluid` but that makes the image disappear completely !

[image]

Comment: You're misusing [label elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) here, by the way. They're intended as companions for form inputs only. See [Is it good practice to use <label> for non-input/non-interactive elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33214093/1264804)

Comment: @isherwood  If you mean use .img-fluid that would default to showing image full size, I dont want that I always want it to be no larger than 400px x 400px, im hapy for it to shrink so can I do that ? And the duplicate answer seems to be saying image needs to shrink but in my screenshot there is still plenty of room for image to be 400 and for the text so it seems the issue is with the text ?

Comment: @isherwood what i want to know is why when you make the screen just a bit smaller the text to the right of the image ends up overlapping the image even though there is still plenty of space for  the text to the right of the image , i.e the problem does not seem to be the image column but the column next to it.

Comment: In your update you show what appears to be a zoomed screen. There should never be horizontal scrollbars with a Bootstrap layout (except maybe when tables are present). Your requirements are still confusing. My second solution doesn't look like that. I've checked Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

Comment: And `img-fluid` _will not_ make your image disappear unless you have serious flaws in your page structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you need to improve your column handling. Apparently you want the first column to be larger on smaller screens, so make it so. Your columns actually only added up to 11 (there are 12 units available), and we can use [cascading classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works) to give the image more space on smaller screens.

Don't put margin on columns. That messes with total width and they'll wrap because they no longer fit the row. Instead, use padding inside or margin on interior elements.

Also put the [responsive image class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/images/#responsive-images) on the image. That's a safety feature so the image never overflows. Use your *grid* to control image size, not width and height attributes. That's not a responsive approach.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 p-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="figure-img border border-dark img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10 p-2">
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Artists
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/artist.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Artists / Sting&amp;cid=0$=Album_Artists$18649" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Sting
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Genre
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/genre.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Genres / Pop rock&amp;cid=0$=Genre$17160" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Pop rock
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Type
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/albumtype.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Types / EP&amp;cid=0$=MusicBrainz Album Type$14830" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  EP
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Label
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Labels / A&amp;M Records&amp;cid=0$=Label$18525" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  A&amp;M Records
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Year
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Years / 1988&amp;cid=0$=Date$789" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  1988
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you *did* want to let the image dictate first column size, you could switch to a purely [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) approach and not use fixed column sizes.

Here I've removed the responsive image class and added some custom CSS for sizing (using [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages) to limit width), replaced column classes with the generic `col`, and set `flex-fill` on the second column so it stretches. There's also a `flex-nowrap` class on the row to keep things horizontal.

```css
.album-image {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap g-0">
    <div class="col p-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="figure-img border border-dark album-image">
    </div>

    <div class="col flex-fill p-2">
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Artists
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/artist.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Artists / Sting&amp;cid=0$=Album_Artists$18649" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Sting
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Genre
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/genre.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Genres / Pop rock&amp;cid=0$=Genre$17160" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  Pop rock
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Album Type
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/albumtype.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Album Types / EP&amp;cid=0$=MusicBrainz Album Type$14830" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  EP
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Label
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Labels / A&amp;M Records&amp;cid=0$=Label$18525" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  A&amp;M Records
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
          <label>
              Year
          </label>
          <span>
              <a href="/container.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=Years / 1988&amp;cid=0$=Date$789" class="h4" style="display:block">
                  1988
              </a>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, but you say 'Apparently you want the first column to be larger on smaller screens'. No I dont, I just dont want it to be smaller on small screens when there is plenty of room for col 2. I did originally have total width =- 12 columns but because it was overlying I tried to use one less column to allow for margins ectera.

Comment: we seem to be talking at cross purposes, this may be because of my quite basic bootstrap knowledge but I dont feel your solution explains the problem. I want the image to be 400x400 unless there really is not enough space in whihc case it can shrink, but i see no reason in my 2nd picture why the image column needs to shrink as there is plenty of space for the text without needing to shrink the image size. So what I want is for the screen2 to look the same as screen1 and continue to look the same until there actually isnt enough room for text and then image can shrink.

Comment: In your second image the photo is _larger than the first column_. This is because you've specified that the first column be 3 of 12 units, or 25% of the available width and the second column take 9 of 12 units, or 75% of the available width, but you have not constrained the image size to its parent element. To fix that, change that. I don't know how to be more clear. My second solution provides exactly what you describe. View the fullscreen demo and resize the screen to see it.

Comment: You might review the [Bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works). I suspect some fundamental misunderstanding that I'm not gleaning.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is the image looks larger in second screenshot, but that is just because the window has been made smaller, the image is still 400px it just takes up a bigger proportion of the window. And I now realize that the issue is not that the text is overlapping the image but the image is overlapping the text because i have set a width is causing image to go over space allowed by col-3. So your second solution basically works for me, your code snippet does work however when i implement it there is one problem the image never shrinks, I do want it to shrink if not enogh room

Comment: I will post more details in question

Comment: The 1st solution nearly works, but the trouble is for larger screens the image is too large so we cant see stuff below the image, and although I can alter the amount of columns allocated to image i can set a fix maxed size it will continue to increase as screen increases.

Comment: It never gets larger than 400px or 40% of the screen, whichever is smaller. Your description doesn't match what I see at all. I've tried all major browsers and I don't get what you posted above. Check browser zoom, and check that you're actually implementing what I suggested.

Comment: Only the second solution do you set album-image class, so surely that 400px limit would only apply to second solution not first.

Comment: Yep. Can't argue with that. You'd just apply the same CSS as in #2. In #1 I was demonstrating the effect of `img-fluid` and column-constrained sizing.

Comment: I've added smaller first and larger second column classes for the large breakpoint in #1. At some point you'll need to grasp the concepts I've shared and run with them to customize further.

Comment: I got it working my adding album-image class to first solution, thanks. I do get the basic concepts, trouble is I dont use bootstrap day to day so forget stuff, also because the bootstrap documentation is pretty good there doesn't seem to be any good bootstrap books (certainly for bootstrap 5), and the documentation does gloss over difficulties.